# Installed Ubuntu upgrade 12.04 and USB external speakers won't work.

Tags: sound, 12.04, usb

Internal speakers and head set work fine.  I am using ACER Aspire 7560-sb416

Comment: Please provide detailed hardware information. Which USB speaker do you use? Please do `lsusb` on the terminal and paste it on [fixee (click)](http://fixee.org) and post the URL here. Then we can help.

Comment: Does the sound device show up in *Sound Settings?*  If not post the output of `dmesg | tail` right after you plug it in

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:
A less then helpful answer but I have found that after shutting down and rebooting, selecting the audioengine in Sound Settings switches the output and the device is working properly.**

**Try rebooting with the device plugged in.**

I have a similar problem with a usb wireless audio device (Audioengine AW1).

The device is recognized in the Sound Settings but clicking on it does not redirect the signal. It still comes through the default speaker (or headphone).

The device worked fine in 11.10.  I've upgraded 'over the air' to 12.04

aplay -l

List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **

card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC262 Analog [ALC262 Analog]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: AW1 [Audioengine AW1], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

lsusb (with Audioengine device):

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 08bb:2704 Texas Instruments Japan

lsusb (without Audioengine device):

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90

Comment: Unbelievable that I had to REALLY reboot my Linux. This was the first time in months if not years. Audio on PCs clearly suck. Yes there I said it, Mac is king.